# How to simplify $\frac{(2K)!}{(K!)^2}$

Tags: factorial

How to simplify $\frac{(2K)!}{(K!)^2}$?

Im learning from class that
$$\frac{(2K)!}{(K!)^2}=\frac{(K+1)(K+2)\cdot ... \cdot2K}{(K!)}$$

But I dont understand how did can I factor $(2K)!$ ?

Comment: Similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913045/need-to-simplify-ratio-test-frac2k12k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that$$(2K)!=(2K)\times(2K-1)\times\cdots\times(K+1)\times\overbrace{K\times(K-1)\times\cdots\times2\times1}^{\phantom{K!}=K!}.$$Therefore,$$\frac{(2K)!}{K!}=(2K)\times(2K-1)\times\cdots\times(K+1)$$and so$$\frac{(2K)!}{(K!)^2}=\frac{(2K)\times(2K-1)\times\cdots\times(K+1)}{K!}.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{8!}{4!^2}=\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4}=\frac{5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4}.$$

See the pattern ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [falling and rising factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials):
$$\small\frac{(2K)!}{(K!)^2}={2K\choose K}=\frac{(2K)^{\underline{K}}}{1^{\overline{K}}}=\frac{(2K)(2K-1)(2K-2)\cdots(K+2)(K+1)}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots(K-1)K}.$$
See more [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2381116/let-me-know-your-opinion-about-simple-formula-to-find-beginpmatrix-n-k-e).

Answer (score 0):

This is the $N=2K$ special case of $$\binom{N}{K}=\frac{1}{K!}\frac{N!}{(N-K)!}=\frac{\prod_{j=N-K+1}^{j=N}j}{K!}.$$